# Capacitor can't find index.html (VueJS)

Tags: android, laravel, vue.js, capacitor

I have an existing/working SPA project built with VueJS on the front and Laravel at the backend.
I'm trying to add an android/ios app using Capacitor.
When I build my project with **npm run prod** it doesn't generate the index.html that Capacitor requires.
So I get this error:

```
The web assets directory (.\public) must contain an index.html file.
        It will be the entry point for the web portion of the Capacitor app.
```

my public folder structure:

```
.
│   .htaccess
│   app.js
│   favicon.ico
│   index.php
│   Logo.png
│   mix-manifest.json
│   robots.txt
│   web.config
├───css
├───images
├───img
└───js
    │   app.js
    │   app.js.LICENSE.txt    
    └───resource
```

Even if I search all folders index.html is nowhere to be seen.
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

### Use `nuxt generate`

This will render all your app views in a single snapshot include an `index.html` entry point, as Capacitor (Android) needs, and ultimately will be submitted as a package to the app store(s). A `dist` folder will be generated, which you'll tell Capacitor about:

**capacitor.config.json**

```
{
    "appId": "com.MyAppDomain",
    "appName": "My Special App",
    "webDir": "dist"
}
```

Any time you deploy an update to the Android/iOS version of your app, you use `nuxt generate` and follow your Capacitor deployment steps (e.g. Capacitor `sync` then appropriate Android or iOS steps).

Side note: Nuxt docs and terminal output will strongly advise you to use `target: static` in conjunction with `nuxt generate`, for some reason, however you can completely ignore this for a typical "web-app-with-servers" situation.

**For your regular web app deployment...**
You continue to simply deploy remotely as you've already been doing, and since you're a "dynamic-web-app-with-a-back-end", you'll never need `nuxt generate`. For most web app setups, the remote app host (e.g. AWS, Heroku, etc) will run the `build` step for you. I use Heroku (for now) and locally, I only ever run `build` myself to: 1. Make final tests, 2. Troubleshoot deployment bugs, 3. Optimize performance (ie reduce package size).

Boiling it down another way: For the lifetime of your (universal) app, `nuxt build` and `nuxt generate` will *both* be used based on what client you are trying to deploy to in the moment.

Answer (score 0):

From your folder structure i think you are running larvel vue and inertia with breeze or jetstream scalffolding. Unfortunately you cant build a capacitor project this way because because only manifest.json and an assets folder is generated during 'npm run build' or 'npm run prod'. If however you still want to create your app using capacitor, you will have to load your website from an iframe.